# Difference and similarities between Intervisibility and Viewshed

Tags: viewshed, terminology

I am just looking for what the difference and similarities for Intervisibility and Viewshed.

Comment: Where did you look for definitions of each?

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, in the Esri documentation and in my text book: "Introductory Digital Image Processing". Just needed a succinct answer to confirm my understanding.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications. By showing how you have already tried to answer your own question will help to avoid it being mistaken for one seeking an assignment answer.

Comment: Got it, can do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intervisibility can be [defined](http://ishm.elte.hu/hun/digkonyv/havas/mellekl/vm25/vmh07.pdf) as the ability to see in a direct line of sight from one position on the Earth's surface to another.

A [Viewshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewshed) is defined by all the points which are visible from one specific position above or on the surface of the Earth. These can be pixels of a DEM for example. Therefore, it's virtually equivalent to the sum of all "intervisibilities" between the given specific position and all other positions of a given area.